# RabbitMQ Management Plugin -configuration unchanged

Tags: rabbitmq

I have installed RaabbitMQ 3.7 in my system and erlang 9.2. I got this problem when trying to enable management plugin:

> C:\Program Files\RabbitMQ Server\rabbitmq_server-3.7.0\sbin>rabbitmq-plugins enable rabbitmq_management
>   Enabling plugins on node rabbit@BDC8-LX-72221DN:
>   rabbitmq_management
>   The following plugins have been configured:
>     rabbitmq_management
>     rabbitmq_management_agent
>     rabbitmq_web_dispatch
>   Applying plugin configuration to rabbit@BDC8-LX-72221DN...
>   Plugin configuration unchanged.

Answer (score 4):

Perhaps this plugin is enabled already.
Check by `rabbitmq-plugins.bat list`.
If you find text like "[E*] rabbitmq_management" then the plugin is enabled.